# Find active members for dates in the past

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data that looks like this:

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id | join_date  | start_date | end_date   |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2005-11-01 | 2005-11-01 | 2014-04-11 |
|  2 | 2007-10-29 | 2007-10-29 | 2011-10-29 |
|  3 | 2005-11-17 | 2005-11-17 | 2014-11-15 |
|  4 | 2006-12-30 | 2009-12-30 | 2013-12-29 |
|  5 | 2005-12-03 | 2011-03-11 | 2013-11-29 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

And the information about the fields above are as follows:

- `join_date` is the date the account was first created.
- `start_date` is the date of the start of an unbroken membership (eg, if
  a member joins in 2005, lapses in 2006, and renews in 2008,
  start_date would have a date in 2008).
- `end_date` is when membership will lapse (whether a time in the future
  or past).

I've been trying to come up with a query that will get me a count of all active members through time (the result being a time series graph of active accounts).

Nothing I've tried has really worked, and I think I just need another perspective. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a calendar table with all available dates?

Comment: What about if one member lapses in 2006, and renews in 2008 and then lapses in 2009, and renews in 2010.
Means this time start date would be a date in 2010 ..right?
and end date would be something in 2009.
Now if you query for some date in 2008 then this member will not come (because you don't have any history table for this, do you).. so tell me are you expecting this member also in this case?

Comment: @pratikgarg I know there are several cases like that, but in this data model, they wouldn't be tracked, because there's no log of lapses. So I know the best I'm going to get is an approximation.

Comment: There are javascript widgets available for graphing json arrays. I'd look into using one of those.